# How to use Reactive Extensions (Rx) LINQ in Python?

Tags: python, reactive-programming, rx-py

I downloaded [RxPY](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY) and was watching the [Rx tutorials](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Rx-Workshop/Rx-Workshop-Schedulers) when I came across:

[image]

So how would I get the above working in Python with RxPY? In particular, the query `q = from x in xs where...` is not syntactically valid Python code -- so how would this be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All LINQ queries in C# could be easily converted to a extension methods ([`where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311043.aspx) is for [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx), and [`select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384087.aspx) is for [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx)):

```
In [20]: from rx import Observable

In [21]: xs = Observable.range(1, 10)

In [22]: q = xs.where(lambda x: x % 2 == 0).select(lambda x: -x)

In [23]: q.subscribe(print)
-2
-4
-6
-8
-10
```

You may also use `filter` instead of `where` and `map` instead of `select`:

```
In [24]: q = xs.filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0).map(lambda x: -x)

In [25]: q.subscribe(print)
-2
-4
-6
-8
-10
```

Comment: Brilliant -- but how did you know about this? Where is this documented?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find actual documentation for `Rx` in Python, however, I supposed, that the same methods should have the same (or similar) names across all implementations of the `Rx` library. I also visited [RxPY github](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY/) and looked through the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The picture you've shown has code in C#, not Python.
In Python it would be as follows:

```
from rx import Observable
xs = Observable.range(1, 10)
q = xs.filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0).map(lambda x: -x)
q.subscribe(print)
```

The general documentation could be found at documentation section at http://reactivex.io.
The Python specific docs are at https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY/blob/master/README.md.